# primary key violation if case sensitive

Tags: asp.net, database, primary-key

Suppose I've the 'dom' table which contains two fields

1. code
2. name

Code should be primary key. In case if I enter values('SD', 'domnic')
then again if I enter ('SD', 'domnic1')
in asp.net I've wrote validation  so i can receive alert message.

```
protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Mode == "Add")
        {
            primarykeyValidation();-------------->validation

            if (strpkval == TextBoxWorkshopid.Text)
            {
                Alert.Show("code Already Exists");
                TextBoxWorkshopid.Text = string.Empty;
                TextBoxWorkshopid.Focus();
                return;
            }
        }
...

public void primarykeyValidation()
{
    DataSet dspkval = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        objaccess.Option = "P";
        objaccess.code= TextBoxWorkshopid.Text;

        dspkval = objaccess.retriveOutsideWorkshops();

        if (dspkval != null && dspkval.Tables.Count != 0 && dspkval.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            strpkval = dspkval.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CODE"].ToString();

        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

In case I enter('sd','domnic') it won't show the message just error thrown due to violation of primary key.

In "P" option  I've wrote query as

```
select code from xxx where code=@code
```

so if i enter small case'sd' then i sholud receive alert message that "code aleady exits but it wouldnt show the 
message........

Answer (score 3):

1)  Configure your database for case sensitivity.  Known as [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx).  It does affect the entire database, though.

2)  You can force a given query to have specific collation: http://web.archive.org/web/20080811231016/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-can-i-make-my-sql-queries-case-sensitive.html.

3)  You could modify the business logic so that all PK values are made upper case before being sent to the database in the first place.  You'd have to do this for updates/inserts as well as queries though, so it could get messy (and be careful that your queries are still [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) i.e. don't put `UPPER(@code)` in your queries - actually modify the value **before** putting it in the parameter).